# Has Trump proposed the following cuts to HIV/AIDS related spending?

Tags: donald-trump

According to [Refusefascism.org](https://refusefascism.org/what-the-trumppence-regime-has-done-and-says-they-will-do/), Trump Administration has proposed the following policies:

> Proposed Trump/Pence budget includes a $186 million funding cut for
>   the Centers for Disease Control’s HIV/AIDS prevention, testing and
>   support programs.
>
> Proposed huge cuts to the National Institutes of Health, including
>   $550 million cuts to HIV/AIDS research.
>
> Proposed $800 million cuts from the President’s Emergency Plan for
>   AIDS Relief (PEPFAR) and U.S. Agency for International Development
>   programs addressing the AIDS pandemic—meaning there will be more than
>   830,000 AIDS treatment interruptions leading to an estimated 130,000
>   more deaths at minimum.

Is the claims true?

My research:

This NYT Article [says](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/23/world/africa/cuts-to-aids-treatment-programs-could-cost-a-million-lives.html):

> The United States currently spends more than $6 billion annually on programs that buy antiretroviral drugs for about 11.5 million people worldwide who are infected with H.I.V., the virus that causes AIDS. The Trump administration has proposed slashing those programs by at least $1.1 billion — nearly a fifth of their current funding, said Jen Kates, a vice president at the Kaiser Family Foundation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR: close (150million cut, not 186 million)**

Source: the [Washington Blade says something very similar to your quote:](http://www.washingtonblade.com/2017/05/31/trump-budget/)

> Among the more drastic cuts is a $186 million reduction in Centers for Disease Control funding for HIV/AIDS, Viral Hepatitis, STIs, and TB prevention. A full $150 million of the reduction would come from HIV/AIDS prevention programs.

But note - according to the blade, "only" 150 million comes from HIV/AIDS prevention, not the full 186 million (the remaining 36 million will apparently come from cuts to prevention programs aimed at Hepatitis, TB, and other STIs).

Comment: I am actually more interested in the second claim about research.